# insert to sql from php gives SQLSTATE[HY093] Error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I have been working on this for a little while trying to insert a statement into my sql.. however I kept getting error messages after looking up online.. please help me :)
below is my code-

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Pokedex(name, nickname, datefound) 
        VALUES (:name, :nickname, :time);";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$params = array(":name" => $lcname, 
                ":nickname" => $nickname, 
                ":datefound" => $time);
$stmt->execute($params);
```

and the error messages seem to complain about my sql:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Pokedex;

CREATE TABLE Pokedex(
   name          VARCHAR(30)     PRIMARY KEY,
   nickname      VARCHAR(30),
   datefound     DATETIME      
);

INSERT INTO Pokedex(name,nickname,datefound) VALUES 
("Pikachu","Pika","2018-01-03 12:23:44");
```

below are the error messages:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined' in /home/ubuntu/workspace/hw7/insert.php on line 45
>
> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in /home/ubuntu/workspace/hw7/insert.php on line 45

```
Call Stack:
    0.0002     238144   1. {main}() /home/ubuntu/workspace/hw7/insert.php:0
    0.0098     249912   2. PDOStatement->execute() /home/ubuntu/workspace/hw7/insert.php:45
```

please help.

Answer (score 0):

`:datefound` is not `:time`. You need to match the named placeholders (`:datefound`), not the column's name (`time`).

Alternatively you could use anonymous `?` placeholders and  put the values in the array in the proper order.

e.g.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Pokedex(name, nickname, datefound) 
        VALUES (?, ?, ?);";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$params = array($lcname, $nickname, $time);
$stmt->execute($params);
```

They bind in the order they occur so the first `?` becomes `$lcname`.

Comment: hello, i have tried your format which led me code to be- 
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Pokedex(name, nickname, datefound) 
            VALUES (:name, :nickname, :datefound);";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $params = array($lcname, 
                    $nickname, 
                    $time);
    $stmt->execute($params);
still gives me error message of [HY093]

Comment: You shouldn't merge the two code bits. Either use your original code and change the binding from `:time` to `:datetime`, OR use the full code snippet I wrote. Note I have no `:...` in my SQL.

Comment: oh yeah.. you are right; i have changed my code to     $sql = "INSERT INTO Pokedex(name, nickname, datefound) 
            VALUES (:name, :nickname, :datefound);";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $params = array(":name" => $lcname, 
                    ":nickname" => $nickname, 
                    ":datefound" => $time);
    $stmt->execute($params);
now it is giving me error message SQLSTATE[23000]

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry..

Comment: Is the `name` you are trying to write already in the DB? The primary requires that field be unique.

Comment: oh dang sorry i didnt see your comment till just now.. $host = getenv('IP');
    $user = getenv('C9_USER');
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "hw7";

    // Create connection
    $ds = "mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8";

    // Make connection
    try {
        $db = new PDO($ds, $user, $password);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);   
    }
thse are the code i have for $db

Comment: Is the value of `$lcname` already in your database? The `primary key` you created requires that column be unique.

Comment: oh wait no $lcname is not; $lcname is lowercased $name.. how can i implement that? like i need the lowercased $name instead of just $name..

Comment: you can also check my sql file from the post i have name but not lcnmae..

Comment: Okay, this is the final answer to your questions. http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php Please accept this answer if it has resolved your issue. Also if using case insensitive the capital/lowercase won't make a different.

Comment: $lcname is my php variable in my php file; so my code has that, yes. however, you did answer my question, these are follow ups, thank you tho!

Answer (score 0):

You have needed to bind the params.
Please try the below code:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO Pokedex(name, nickname, datefound) VALUES (:name, :nickname, :time);";
 $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
 $stmt->bindParam(':name', $lcname);
 $stmt->bindParam(':nickname', $nickname);
 $stmt->bindParam(':time', $time);
 $lcname = "John Doe";
 $nickname = "john";
 $time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
 $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: thank you!! i know receive an error SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 but i think that is a different kind of issue i have now..